# Java sorting with lambda function

Tags: java, sorting, comparison, comparator

Can someone please convert this function into lambda function... I am having some trouble in typecasting I guess. Help please

```java
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item item1, Item item2) {
        double cpr1 = new Double((double) item1.value / (double) item1.weight);
        double cpr2 = new Double((double) item2.value / (double) item2.weight);
 
        if (cpr1 < cpr2) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `Item`?

Comment: Use an  IDE and apply the "convert to lambda" quick fix.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but your comparator is wrong. It should return 0 if the values are equal, not -1.

Comment: @Sweeper Item is a class having two attributes, int value and int weight.

Comment: @Jorn I use VS Code and I can't seem to find the "quick fix" for this case.. as far as I know quick fix option comes when there is some error. How to use it in this case though?

Comment: @Arya I'm not familiar with VSCode. IntelliJ will do it just fine, and I'd guess VSCode can too. Just not sure how.

Comment: Why are you using `new Double`? All that does is box the `double` to a `Double` which is then immediately unboxed. Perhaps the compiler will realize that and eliminate it for you, but it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out few things and I finally found the solution:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (item1, item2) -> Double.compare((double) item2.value / item2.weight, (double) item1.value / item1.weight));
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Even simpler: `Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingDouble(item -> (double)item.value / item.weight));`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  var arr = new Item[]{}; 
  Arrays.sort(arr, MyClass::useMySorting);
}

private static int useMySorting(Item item1, Item item2) {
  double cpr1 = new Double((double) item1.value / (double) item1.weight);
  double cpr2 = new Double((double) item2.value / (double) item2.weight);
  if (cpr1 < cpr2)
    return 1;
  else
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).